# Помогите вывести при нажатии на кнопку определённую последовательность: 10 0 9 1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5 5 4 6 3 7 2 8 1 9 0 10

Tags: javascript, html

> Кнопка b-15 запускает функцию t15 Функция должна выводить следующую последовательность в  div.out-15:

```js
function t15() {
   let out = document.querySelector('.out-15');
   let  i = 0;
   while (i < 10) {
     i++;
     out.innerHTML += (10 - i) + ' ' + i;;
   }
}
```

```html
<button class="b-15" onclick="t15();">GO</button>
<div class="out-15"></div>
```

Comment: Если запустить ваш код, то видно, что всего лишь пробела не хватает на каждой итерации. Как его добавить идей совсем нет?

Comment: @Leonid не совсем. там ещё 10-ки  в начале не хватает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function t15() {
  let out = document.querySelector('.out-15');
  let text = '';

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {  
    text += `${10 - i} ${i} `;
  }
   
  out.innerHTML = text;
}

document.querySelector('.b-15').addEventListener('click', () => {
    t15();
});
```

```html
<button class="b-15">GO</button>
<div class="out-15"></div>
```

Comment: А зачем нужен самый последний пробел? Лучше его убрать: **out.innerHTML = text.substring(0, text.length - 1));**

Comment: Да можно вообще всё в массив записывать и потом `join(' ')` сделать. Но это уже автору самому надо решать что ему нужно